# UIWebView App Issue With ViewPort Meta Tag on iOS 8

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, ios8

I am trying to set the viewport of my iOS 8 UIWebView App to 500 when it loads my html page. This is the code I am using and it worked fine on iOS versions under 8, fitting the whole screen. But now in iOS 8, it leaves a blank area on the right side. Any help is sincerely appreciated.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1:**

Seeing as this is a question about getting the website to fill the entire screen on an iPhone I would ***highly*** recommend looking into a responsive css framework such as [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

Then instead of setting the screen to `500px` the application would adjust to the screen size of the phone. This is *very* useful when working with both portrait and landscape view changes *and* even moreso now with the addition of the new screen sizes on the iPhone 6 and 6+.

**Part 2:**

Now I say that with the understanding that re-writing your UI with a css framework can be **a lot** of work (*though completely worth it for the benefits*)

To more directly address your question... If you connect your test device to your mac and open safari and inspect the page (make sure to press the refresh button in the resources tab next to your index.html so it catches all errors and events from page load) do you see any errors or messages about the `content="width=500"` being invalid or unrecognized?

**Note to reviewers:**

I believe that this is a *solution* to the OP's issue, not a direct answer to his question. It answers the issue of his application "fitting the whole screen" and therefore I believe it answers the question's intent.